# Printing issue with SSRS report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2012

I have run into a problem with an SSRS report..... The report will generate around 20 pages, with unique data on each page. I have used a page break to do this.
At the top of each page is some data referring to each page.... a vehicle reg number, a driver name etc. This data is coming from an expression. `reportitems!.columnName.Value & reportitems!.columnName.Value`When the report is run, in design mode, or viewed in Chrome after being deployed, each page has the correct data at the top of the page.... the driver name changes etc.

However, when the report is printed from the browser, or exported to a PDF, the data at the top of each page is now the same. Basically page 1 info is repeated on each page. The report data is still unique on each page, but the reference at the top has now repeated.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem, or any idea what may be causing this? I am very confused, as before printing, the report is showing all data as expected.

[image]
[image]

The 2 images show page 1 and 2 of the report, both numbers in the expression are different.

[image]

This image shows page 1 and 2 in the PDF, both numbers are now the same.

Comment: Is the behaviour the same when exporting to say Excel?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze Yes, when exported to excel, the data from sheet1 is now repeated on each sheet. Just to clarify, only the data in the expression is repeated, and before being exported or printed, the expression returns different data for each page.

Comment: Can you include some screen shots in the question?

Comment: View the RDL file in notepad++, or similar, for any discrepancies

Comment: How are you setting the page breaks? Is the report grouping data with a break between groups or some other method?

Comment: @AlanSchofield one of the row groups is `Vehicle_reg`, page breaks are set between each instance of a group. This is set in group properties for `Vehicle_reg`. One of the `reportitems` in the expression refers to `vehicle_reg`